# File is in the directory but isDirectory() returning false for a file

Tags: java, javascript

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
String fileName = "High_Scores";
File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");
if(file.isFile())
  System.out.println("its a file");
if(!file.isDirectory())
   System.out.println("Not in directory");

if(file.delete())
  System.out.println("deleted");
else
  System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

File file2  = new File(fileName + "2.txt");
boolean success = file2.renameTo(file);
if(success == true)
  System.out.println("renamed");
else
  System.out.println(file2.getAbsolutePath());
```

What happens is that isFile() returns true, isDirectory() returns false; and the delete and renameTo methods won't work.  I have no idea why isDirectory() returns false since both file and file2 are created in the java project folder.  Thanks.

Comment: Are `file` and `file2` directories? Doesn't seem like it. Read the javadoc. You misunderstand what `isDirectory` means.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding as to what `isDirectory()` tells you. It's not whether a file is in any directory, it's true if the path of the file IS a directory and note a file. `C:\SomeFolder\` is a directory. `C:\SomeFolder\SomeText.txt` is not a directory.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 7):

You may have a slight misunderstanding of the `file.isDirectory()` method. It returns `true` if the file itself IS a directory, not if the file is IN a directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be misunderstanding what `File.isDirectory()` does. From the java 7 API:

```
public boolean isDirectory()
Tests whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a directory.
Where it is required to distinguish an I/O exception from the case that the file is not a directory, or where several attributes of the same file are required at the same time, then the Files.readAttributes method may be used.

Returns:
true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a directory; false otherwise
Throws:
SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkRead(java.lang.String) method denies read access to the file
```

from: [Java 7 File API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29)

So indeed, it is testing to see if that file IS a directory, not whether or not it is inside of it :)

+1 upvote to quazzieclodo, he beat me to it! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a file with:

```
new File
```

you are missing following code:

```
File file2  = new File(fileName + "2.txt");
file2.createNewFile();
```